# Is there a reason to use Scheme over JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, scheme

As far as I know, `JavaScript` can be used to do everything that is possible in `Scheme`.

Every functional programming paradigm I've learnt in `Scheme` is doable in `JavaScript`.

I know that one may end up using `JavaScript` to write ungood code (ones with global variables, too many states and side effects) where as `Scheme` restricts one to write `functional` code.

But apart from that, is it really necessary to use `Scheme` anywhere over `JavaScript`?

For those of you who say `JavaScript` can be interpreted only on a browser kindly draw the same question to `Python` and `Scheme`.

Comment: "Every functional programming paradigm I've learnt in Scheme is doable in JavaScript"  You need to learn more...

Comment: @GoZoner, please can you name some Scheme concepts which don't fit the bill in JavaScript?

Comment: How does Scheme restrict you do functional code?  `set!`, `set-car!`, and `set-cdr!` are just the beginning…

Comment: hygienic macros, reentrant continuations, dynamic-wind, quasiquotation to name a handful.  http://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2013/07/18/javascript-isnt-scheme/

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor, yeah, but atleast it doesn't encourage us to do that. JS on the other hand happily offers `OOP` stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Let me pose a similar question:

Is there a reason to use French over English? Anything that you can express in French you can express in English, so is it really necessary to use French over English? Kindly draw the same question to Russian, German, Spanish, or any other spoken language you choose.

No programming language is completely unique, anything you can do in one language can be done in a different language, some implementations might require a bit more creative thought but it can still be done.

Some reasons to use Scheme instead of JavaScript or Python:

- You appreciate the simplistic and minimalist structure of the
  language
- Ease of implementation when compared to expressive power    (lambda
  expressions)
- You are more familiar with Scheme
- The client has    existing code in Scheme

Specific implementations or algorithms might have a min/max calculation available to give exact benchmarks, but you would have to look at specific algorithms. In general there is no way to define one language as always better in all situations (or even 'never worse'), and trying to pigeon hole oneself into a single language is dangerous. In my opinion, open mindedness is one of the biggest strengths a programmer can have. Being able and willing to use different languages or techniques can be a powerful tool.

I personally suggest further reading by looking up Polyglot Programming. It isn't directly related to your question, but it is a mentality that speaks to the benefits of knowing and using a variety of languages.